# development and debugging base ground

Tags: debugging, deployment, development-environment

I am new here and I want some help to put me on the right direction.

I am developing this website using apache and php on windows server from scratch. No frameworks except jQuery.

We released a couple of weeks ago and now I am running into the issue of debugging and releasing.

The way I'm debugging and releasing, for instant page contact.php, I would create a copy of the current page under a different name (contact_test.php) and debug it. Once I'm done, I'd delete contact.php and replace it with contact_test.php and rename it to contact.php

I know it's an immature way of doing it but that's why I'm asking.

I heard php-deployer is the way to do it but I am not familiar with it or how it works.

Suggestions? Opinions?

Cheers

Comment: Suggestions and opinions are not appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your approach. As your app grows more sophisticated and requires updates to many source files across a project with revisions you might find it helpful to operate a separate dev server with its own branch of sources. This also enables someone other than you (QA test partner, end user/client) to approve changes prior to moving to production.